# ELAN trackpad driver

Tags: drivers

my touchpad works for a few minutes on boot, but then proceeds to cut out. this is becoming a bit of a nightmare for me. my laptop has a touchscreen (thank god) but is also elan and behaves oddly. Thanks for the help!

(HP pavilion 15-dy0518sa, 23.04, 6.2.0-20-generic)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting, please edit your question to include the output of `sudo dmesg.` You're looking for any warnings/errors might provide some clues as to why your touchpad is failing. Thanks